# How to make beveled hole without boolean

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I am trying to make a hole through my object without using boolean, but my hole is beveled. It looks something like this:
[image]

Is there a way to do this without boolean?

Comment: You can use the Knife Project tool but why don't you want to use boolean in this case?

Comment: @moonboots Because of topology, I wanna use quads

Comment: Is your object flat or is a cube? do you have a reference image? maybe share your object?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to recreate this charger hole into my iphone model  https://imgur.com/a/J509vJk

Comment: boolean is not necessarily a problem, nor tris and ngons, also if you plan to use a Subdivision Surface you can use less vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be not a problem to use tris for example, but if you want quads only you could go the other way around, extrude your shape:

[image]

Then flatten its edges to have your square:

[image]

Note: Boolean is not necessarily a problem, nor tris and ngons, also if you plan to use a *Subdivision Surface* you can use less vertices. Topology with tris:

[image]